Extend TypeScript type with different variable names
I am trying to extend a TypeScript type that that is used for the props of a React component.
type myType = {  // this is imported from another file
  variable1: string;
  variable2: boolean;
};

interface  myInterface extends myType {
  anExtraVariable: string;
}

const myComponent: React.FC<myInterface> = ({ differentVariable1, differentVariable2, anExtraVariable }) => {
  return (...);
};

differentVariable1 and differentVariable2 have the same type as variable1 and variable2 from myType.
Any help would be appreciated.

Are you looking for type ExtendedType = MyType & { anExtraVariable: string }?

@knittl Probably not, because that would be more or less the same as interface ExtendedType extends MyType { anExtraVariable: string}. As I understand it, ExtendedType should have differentVariable1: string and differentVariable2: boolean instead of variable1: string and variable2: boolean

@derpirscher ah! I missed that the properties were renamed as well. Not sure if I would count this as "extending" though – the new type does not share anything with the original type.

Did you try define the type of your different variables when you extend myType?
Example:
interface myInterface extends myType {
 differentVariable1: myType['variable1']; // Uses the type of 'variable1' from myType
 anExtraVariable: string; 
}


Thank you for your help. It frustrates me how difficult it is to find the solution to such a simple problem.

As we approach the end of 2024, I strongly encourage you to use AI wisely to enhance your skills and achieve your goals.

@SG52  The emphasis is on "wisely" because often the answers given by AI are just garbage ... Ie whatever ChatGPT tells you, use it with care and do a cross check ...

@derpirscher You're absolutely right! It's crucial to always evaluate and verify the results through thorough testing.
